# vim - white line on the left side of the screen?

Tags: vim

when I'm using DiffOrig command from vimrc_example, after i close the diff screens, my file is altered with some white line on the left side. How can i remove that without reopening the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use :diffoff : the white line will be removed and the created folds will be deleted.

Comment: *did*. Also, you may want to accept Pikrass' answer: just tick it.